# 1 group; 4 variables; small sample - can I compare means?

Tags: t-test, mean, small-sample

I have a small sample (n = 16) that completed 4 questionnaires. I am trying to determine if any of the questionnaire mean scores are significantly higher than the others.

The data isn't normally distributed (negatively skewed). Say this assumption is met, would I have other options?

Is there anything I can do with this data?